# All of the navigation bar's items are appearing on the left of the page

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
 <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark navbar-change" id="main_navbar">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
            <img class="logoHeadstart-responsive" src="images/Logo_web_h59px.png" alt="Headstart Malaysia">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse rounded" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" id="menu">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
               <li class="nav-item navbar-fixed-top">
                    <button style="color: #0756a5" class="nav-link dropbtn" onclick="location.href='aboutUs.html'">About</button>
                    <ul style="list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;" class="dropdown-content rounded">
                        <li><a href="aboutUs.html#aboutUs-anchor">Overview</a>
                        <li><a href="#">Facilities</a>
                            <ul style="list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-left: 30px" class="dropdown-content rounded">
                                <li><a href="aboutUs.html#facilities-anchor">Academy@SACC</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Therapy@Damansara</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Team</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>


                <li class="nav-item navbar-fixed-top">
                    <button style="color: #0756a5" class="nav-link dropbtn" onclick="location.href='#'">Intervention</button>
                    <ul style="list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;" class="dropdown-content rounded">
                        <li><a href="eip.html#overview-anchor" class="eip-text"><span>Early Intervention</span></a>
                            <ul style="list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-left: 30px" class="dropdown-content rounded">
                                <li><a href="eip.html#overview-anchor">Overview</a></li>
                                <li><a href="eip.html#admission-anchor">Admission</a></li>
                                <li><a href="eip.html#calendar-anchor">Timetable</a></li>
                                <li><a href="eip.html#academic-calendar-anchor">Calendar</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <!--<li><a href="#">Junior <span style="background-color: #F18805" class="badge badge-secondary animated pulse">COMING SOON</span></a>-->
                        <ul style="list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-left: 30px" class="dropdown-content rounded">
                            <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Admission</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Timetable</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Calendar</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="eip.html#devmilestones-anchor">Developmental Milestones</a>

                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item navbar-fixed-top">
                    <button style="color: #0756a5" class="nav-link dropbtn" onclick="location.href='therapy.html'">Therapy</button>
                    <ul style="list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;" class="dropdown-content rounded">
                        <li><a href="therapy.html">Academy@SACC Mall</a>
                            <ul style="list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-left: 30px" class="dropdown-content rounded">
                                <li><a href="therapy.html">Behaviour</a></li>
                                <li><a href="therapy.html">Speech</a></li>
                                <li><a href="therapy.html">Occupational</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="therapy.html">Therapy@Damansara</a>
                            <ul style="list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-left: 30px" class="dropdown-content rounded">
                                <li><a href="therapy.html">Speech</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>


                <li class="nav-item navbar-fixed-top"><div class="dropdown">
                    <button style="color: #0756a5" class="nav-link dropbtn" onclick="location.href='eca.html'">ECA</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content rounded">
                        <a href="eca.html#eca-anchor">Overview</a>
                        <a href="eca.html#classes-anchor">Classes</a>
                        <a href="eca.html#eca-timetable-anchor">Timetable</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
                </li>             
                </div>
                </li>


            </ul>

        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

I'm creating a page for my company's website. So, I have to use the same header as in the website. But when I paste it, it is appearing on the left of the page.

Previously, I have tried in another version of the page which has pagination coding, it worked. But when I tried in the version, which has the collapsing posts function, it's not working.

the navigation bar should be horizontal that has drop down function. But it appears stick to the left hand side of the page

Im quite new to this page and basically web dev.

[It should appear like this. A normal looking horizontal navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaJt3.png)
[Unfortunately, it appears like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0zbN.png)

Comment: can you please show us what you have done so, it would be easy to hel you out

Comment: Please do provide the code part so that it could be easy for people to help you

Comment: Hi Nathiyaa. Welcome to SO. I would request to go through Stack Overflow's question asking guideline. More specifically, can you please provide us with a minimal, working and reproducible example of what you have tried and what went wrong?

Comment: Not sure on what the issue could be without seeing the snippet of the code, but one of the reason could be the not loading of JavaScript/CSS files needed to display that header properly.

Comment: I have already updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install bootstrap or link to it in your html file:

in your head tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

in your body tag (better at the end, before the closing tag):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

[See the example here](https://codepen.io/gaetan-peltier/pen/GRKLGaz) I just link to bootstrap CDN through CodePen and it work, i didn't change anything in the code you provided

```
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark navbar-change" id="main_navbar">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
            <img class="logoHeadstart-responsive" src="images/Logo_web_h59px.png" alt="Headstart Malaysia">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse rounded" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" id="menu">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
               <li class="nav-item navbar-fixed-top">
                    <button style="color: #0756a5" class="nav-link dropbtn" onclick="location.href='aboutUs.html'">About</button>
                    <ul style="list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;" class="dropdown-content rounded">
                        <li><a href="aboutUs.html#aboutUs-anchor">Overview</a>
                        <li><a href="#">Facilities</a>
                            <ul style="list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-left: 30px" class="dropdown-content rounded">
                                <li><a href="aboutUs.html#facilities-anchor">Academy@SACC</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Therapy@Damansara</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Team</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>


                <li class="nav-item navbar-fixed-top">
                    <button style="color: #0756a5" class="nav-link dropbtn" onclick="location.href='#'">Intervention</button>
                    <ul style="list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;" class="dropdown-content rounded">
                        <li><a href="eip.html#overview-anchor" class="eip-text"><span>Early Intervention</span></a>
                            <ul style="list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-left: 30px" class="dropdown-content rounded">
                                <li><a href="eip.html#overview-anchor">Overview</a></li>
                                <li><a href="eip.html#admission-anchor">Admission</a></li>
                                <li><a href="eip.html#calendar-anchor">Timetable</a></li>
                                <li><a href="eip.html#academic-calendar-anchor">Calendar</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <!--<li><a href="#">Junior <span style="background-color: #F18805" class="badge badge-secondary animated pulse">COMING SOON</span></a>-->
                        <ul style="list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-left: 30px" class="dropdown-content rounded">
                            <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Admission</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Timetable</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Calendar</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="eip.html#devmilestones-anchor">Developmental Milestones</a>

                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item navbar-fixed-top">
                    <button style="color: #0756a5" class="nav-link dropbtn" onclick="location.href='therapy.html'">Therapy</button>
                    <ul style="list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;" class="dropdown-content rounded">
                        <li><a href="therapy.html">Academy@SACC Mall</a>
                            <ul style="list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-left: 30px" class="dropdown-content rounded">
                                <li><a href="therapy.html">Behaviour</a></li>
                                <li><a href="therapy.html">Speech</a></li>
                                <li><a href="therapy.html">Occupational</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="therapy.html">Therapy@Damansara</a>
                            <ul style="list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-left: 30px" class="dropdown-content rounded">
                                <li><a href="therapy.html">Speech</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>


                <li class="nav-item navbar-fixed-top"><div class="dropdown">
                    <button style="color: #0756a5" class="nav-link dropbtn" onclick="location.href='eca.html'">ECA</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content rounded">
                        <a href="eca.html#eca-anchor">Overview</a>
                        <a href="eca.html#classes-anchor">Classes</a>
                        <a href="eca.html#eca-timetable-anchor">Timetable</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
                </li>             
                </div>
                </li>


            </ul>

        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```